# Why notifyItemChanged(int position) of RecyclerView is working only once than thrice?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-volley, notifydatasetchanged

I am trying to replicate the action of Recyclerview methods wherein I am having 3 items in ArrayList itemname and also stored in sqlite table. Corresponding to each item name an 'id' is assigned in the table. Here I want that for each below iteration all the 3 items shall change color as per the condition defined in the onBindViewHolder() method of the Adapter class.

```
for (int i=0; i<itemname.size(); i++) {   
String query = "SELECT id FROM sec_table WHERE address='"+itemname.get(i)+"'";
                 Cursor c1 = SecDB.rawQuery(query,null);

                 if (c1 != null && c1.getCount() != 0)
                 {
                     while (c1.moveToNext()) {
                         id = c1.getInt(c1.getColumnIndex("id"));
                     }
                        c1.close();
                 }

      alert_position = id;                // Class variable 'alert_position'
      userAdapter.notifyItemChanged(alert_position);
}
```

The onBindViewHolder() method is responsible for changing the color of the cards as per the value of the position variable in the Main class.

```
@Override                // Inside the Adapter class
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final UserViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    final SecurityDetails userDetails = secDetailsList.get(position);
    LogsDatabaseHelper logsDBHelper = new LogsDatabaseHelper(context);


    SecurityDatabaseHelper secDBHelper = new SecurityDatabaseHelper(context);
    LogsDB = logsDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    SecDB = secDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    if (requestQueue==null)
    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);      // Creating RequestQueue...

    holder.tvName.setText(userDetails.getName());

    if(position == Security.alert_position) {
        Toast.makeText(context, position+"", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        holder.state.setText("< Activity Detected >");
        holder.state.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        holder.cards.setBackgroundColor(0x33FF0000);
    }
  }
```

Here the above for loop is changing the color of the last card only although it is feeding position values 1,2,3 simultaneously to the notifyItemChanged().

---

But when the same logic of updating the cards is performed via android Volley all 3 cards are turning red one by one. The volley method is shown below:

```
for (int i=0; i<itemname.size(); i++) {   // Calls the Volley method with different items name from arraylist
      CardsUpdate(itemname.get(i));
}

private void CardsUpdate(final String email) {
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, "http://plateau.com/SecuritySensorUpdate.php", new Response.Listener<String>()
    {
        int id;
        @Override
         public void onResponse(String ServerResponse) {
            if (ServerResponse.equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                values.put(SecurityDatabaseContract.UserDatabase2.SEC_NAME_COL4, "1");
                SecDB.update(SecurityDatabaseContract.UserDatabase2.TABLE_NAME2, values, "address='" + email + "'", null);

                String query = "SELECT id FROM sec_table WHERE address='" + email + "'";
                Cursor c1 = SecDB.rawQuery(query, null);

                if (c1 != null && c1.getCount() != 0) {
                    while (c1.moveToNext()) {
                        id = c1.getInt(c1.getColumnIndex("id"));
                    }
                    c1.close();
                }

                alert_position = id;
                userAdapter.notifyItemChanged(alert_position);
            }
            else
                Toast.makeText(Security.this, ServerResponse, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }},
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                  //  Toast.makeText(Security.this, volleyError.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            })
    {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams()
        {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("email", email);
            return params;
        }};

    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);        // Adding the StringRequest object into requestQueue.
}
```

Kindly suggest some workaround to achieve the desired output of updating the colors of all 3 cards.

Comment: welcome to SO. you're not using list view here, right ? I've removed the tag for it, seems like you're using a recycler

Answer (score 1):

1. I would use a `ListAdapter<T, K>` (from RecyclerView).
2. During the Cursor iteration, I would create (or modify) a new List based on the new values.
3. I would then submit a new list to the adapter (ListAdapter has a method called `submitList(T)`.

Since you need to provide a "Diff Util" callback to the ListAdapter, it will take care of rebinding the views whose data has changed.

If you *really* want "real-time" one by one changing, then you'd need to dive deeper into having a ViewModel expose a state (perhaps a `Flow`) that you can observe and react to each `emit(...)`.

There are alternatives here, but I would try the ListAdapter first, it's included in Android, and would likely work fine.

If you need help setting up a List Adapter, and because I've been asked this question over 9000 times, I have created [the simplest recycler view sample over at GitHub](https://github.com/Gryzor/TheSimplestRV/tree/main/app/src/main/java/com/example/thesimplestrv) I can imagine :)

Answer (score 0):

calls to `notifyItemChanged()` are not synchronous, i.e. `onBindViewHolder()` will be called at a later time.  By the time `onBindViewHolder()` is called, the static property `Security.alert_position` contains the newest value (from the 3rd time through the loop).

**Recommendations:**

Add Log statements to your call to `notifyItemChanged()` and `onBindViewHolder()`.  You'll likely see that `notifyItemChanged()` calls precede the calls to `onBindViewHolder()`.  Log the position and `Security.alert_position` values in `onBindViewHolder()`, this should explain why you're seeing what you're seeing.

```
Log.d("MY-TAG", String.format("calling notifyItemChanged(%d)", alert_position));
```

**in onBindViewHolder()**

```
Log.d("MY-TAG", String.format("onBindViewHolder(%d), Security.alert_position=%d", position, Security.alert_position));
```

I suspect you'll see the three calls to `onBindViewHolder()` showing correct position values (1,2,3), but `Security.alert_position` will always be 3.

While this recommendation won't solve your program logic, it will hopefully help you understand what's occurring.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out but why the same is working well via the Volley method? Also, could you please suggest some workaround where I could refresh all the 3 cards simultaneously rather than the last one only. Although the volley method seems to be working fine but now I had shifted to Firebase.

Comment: @Jennifer, I'm not 100% clear on what you're trying to accomplish. You can force an entire `RecyclerView` reload using `notifyDataSetChanged()` instead of `notifyItemChanged()`, this will re-create and re-bind all the view, the item whose `position == Security.alert_position` will get colored Red.  Regarding the Volley method, I don't see a loop, only a single `notifyItemChanged()` call, so `Security.alert_position` would have a predictable value.  The suggested logging should help you better understand what's happening.

Comment: Well, I am having a Recyclerview which I am inflating by fetching data from MySQL/Firebase. Each card represents a wireless sensor with a specific name tag in DB. This sensor is fetched and stored in SQLite local DB with a corresponding id. In order to constantly monitor the online state of the sensor, MySQL is queried via Volley and if a value "1" is received from the database then the card for that sensor is turned red.  If all 3 sensors are turned on then they must turn red. Here notifyDataSetChanged() is also turning only the last card red. The volley method is called via for loop.

Comment: for (int i=0; i<itemname.size(); i++) {   // Calls the Volley method with different items name from arraylist
      CardsUpdate(itemname.get(i));
}

Comment: Although Firebase onDataSetChange() method is turning the cards Red in real-time i.e. the moment sensor state changes and the sensor activity class or Recyclerview is open on screen but when the sensors are already active and the sensor activity is launched then the issue of only the last card being Red crops up.

Comment: your data model (use of static property `Security.alert_position`) only supports a single item being highlighted red.  This highlighting indicator needs to be part of your `SecurityDetails` class, or some `List` as suggest by @MartinMarconcini

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution. The same can be achieved by adding positions to Arraylist and then further calling that ArrayList via a for loop within the Recyclerview adapter class by iteration.

```
 if (tokens[0].equals("1")) {
                     power_position.add(id);
                     userAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                 }
```

And within the Recyclerview adapter class.

```
for (int i=0; i<Security.alert_position.size(); i++) {
        if (position == Security.alert_position.get(i)) {
            holder.state.setText("< Data Changed >");
            holder.state.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            holder.cards.setBackgroundColor(0x33FF0000);
        }
    }
```

This will refresh the Recyclerview at once rather than calling individual recycler view items for updates.